# How to get a regex that takes on numbers from user

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to write a regex for US phone numbers where user can enter the number and dash comes automatically.
But here the drawback is if user enters "123" and then "-" the regex breaks and instead of 123-456-7890 it becomes 123-4567890 
Here is the regex code:

```
  $('#AccountFrm_telephone').attr('maxlength', '12');

$('#AccountFrm_telephone').keyup(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d)+$/, "$1-$2-$3"));
});
```

Maybe There is something that we add in regex so that user can not type dash?

Comment: this part `(\d)+` should be `(\d+)`

Comment: @Nullman No thats not working :(

Comment: i ave put your string into `var x` and the following worked fine `x.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)$/, "$1-$2-$3")`

Comment: I tried it but it takes dash "-" after 3 number if user enters "-" then breaks the regex still

Comment: ah, then like the removed post suggested, use this: `/^(\d{3})-?(\d{3})-?(\d+)$/, "$1-$2-$3"` the `?` notes 0 or 1 times

Comment: Yup this works thanks @Nullman

Comment: Doesn't a onkey up handler return on _each_ key up ? If so, you won't get a complete phone number, so using `^(\d{3})-?(\d{3})-?(\d+)$/` will never match. I wouldn't do it this way. I'd use a regex to strip it down to 1-10 numbers. Then use a string function to _insert_ a dash - at the right places if the string is long enough.

Comment: `Maybe There is something that we add in regex so that user can not type dash` - If this _is_ an onkeyup type handler, you should be able to write over whatever key character is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for completes:
you have 2 issues
first this part `(\d)+` should be `(\d+)` or you wont capture the last group on numbers correctly.
the second part is that you aren't handling possible dashes in the input, so try something like:

```
.replace(/^(\d{3})-?(\d{3})-?(\d+)$/, "$1-$2-$3")
```

the question marks (?) denote 0 or 1 times, meaning the user can input the dashes if he wants

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try the following:

```js
$('#AccountFrm_telephone').attr('maxlength', '12');

$('#AccountFrm_telephone').keyup(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$("#input1").on('keyup', e => {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/(\d{3})-?(\d{3})-?(\d+)/, '$1-$2-$3')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1">
```